# How to write compactly the difference of multiple set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let's say I have three sets and I want their differences like the following:
$$
\mathbb{R} \setminus
\{ k\pi : k\in \mathbb{Z}\} \setminus
\left\{ \frac { (2k+1) \pi} {2} : k \in \mathbb{Z} \right\}
$$

Is it possible to write this more compactly as
$$
\mathbb{R} \setminus \left\{ k\pi, \frac { (2k+1) \pi} {2} : k \in \mathbb{Z} \right\}
$$

Comment: Your more compact version has $k\pi^2+\frac{1}{2}$. I suppose this is a typo. I would write $\Bbb R\setminus S$ with $S=\pi\Bbb Z \cup \frac{1}{2}\pi \Bbb Z$.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the typo! I fixed it

Comment: Your set notation is not good, with a comma. Better is $\Bbb R\setminus (\pi\Bbb Z\cup \frac{\pi}{2}\Bbb Z)$.